# "Real me" VS "The real me"

Tags: articles

Real me is handsome.

VS

The real me is handsome.

Are both correct? And are they different in meaning?

If "The real me is handsome." is correct, why should put "the" into the sentence?

Comment: It's up to the author/speaker.  Omitting "the" makes "real me" a sort of quasi proper name.

Comment: @HotLicks. Yes, but “the real me” is the idiomatic form and “real me”, as a sort of name, is much less common.

Comment: We usually include "the", just as we say, "The big house is expensive and the blue ball is bouncy," not "Big house is expensive and blue ball is bouncy." "The real me" is idiomatic, as the Orbital Aussie says. Usually we speak of the 'real me' to distinguish it from any 'me' in photographs: "I look pig-ugly in photos but *the real me is handsome*." This posits two "me's", and they are not "real one and one in the photos", but ***the*** real one and ***the*** one in the photos. The real me is more handsome than the me in photos.

Comment: *Real me* is more colloquial and modern (and a bit silly).